# Interactive Brokers CFDs without leverage

Tags: stocks, cfd

I would like to buy a certain stock that is not available in my currency and also an index fund. I see there is the option to buy it with CFD but I cannot find it in the documentation or through search if it is possible to buy this without leverage reason being I want to go long with a long-term horizon on them and I am not sure of how to apply a currency hedge.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand.  You are looking to buy the stock and *also* buy an index fund?  Does the index fund have anything to do with your question?  I assume it is available in your desired currency?

Comment: are indices from other parts of the world available in my desired currency (EUR?). In general my question is about buying something that I cannot buy with my currency as CFD without borrowing money. I put up an answer actually.

Comment: @arisalexis, were you able to set up your IB account to none leverage for CFDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site support confirmed this is possible with setting margin at 100% so you can buy a CFD without borrowing money and no interest rate fees.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, and given that derivative exposure involves risk factors not necessarily associated with underlying exposure, I think that this tutorial on how to hedge away the currency risk associated with the purchase of stock in something other than your base currency may be helpful:

https://ibkr.info/video/1172